# Weird org parser error on non org-files?

Tags: org-mode

I have annoying org-mode warnings popping out as soon as I open LaTeX or lisp files and browsing them. Here are the typical error I get:

`Warning (org-element-cache): org-element--cache: Org parser error in main.tex::42. Resetting. The error was: (error "rx ‘**’ range error")`

I don't get why org is related to non-org files.

I'm running GNU Emacs 29.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin23.1.0, NS appkit-2487.20
Version 14.1.1 (Build 23B81)) of 2024-02-06

Here are the packages I have installed (and org 9.6.15)

```
 auctex                       14.0.3 
 auto-compile          20240101.2210 
 cdlatex                20231118.645 
 dired-ranger          20230512.1107 
 dired-subtree         20230512.1107 
 elpy                  20240109.1445 
 exec-path-from-shell  20240216.1606 
 flyspell-correct       20220520.630 
 google-this           20170810.1215 
 lsp-latex             20240215.1159 
 lsp-ui                 20230811.552 
 magit                         3.3.0 
 ob-ipython             20180224.953 
 orderless             20240225.1842 
 org-appear            20231127.1052 
 org-download          20220906.1929 
 org-transclusion              1.3.2 
 ox-hugo               20221028.1631 
 undo-fu               20230808.1340 
 vertico                         1.7
```

Comment: What modes are active in the buffer (major mode and any minor modes)? Do `C-h m` and report back.

Comment: Thanks. ```Minor modes: Auto-Save Buffer-Face Company
Eldoc Flyspell Font-Lock Lsp-Completion Lsp-Diagnostics Lsp-Managed
Lsp Lsp-Modeline-Code-Actions Lsp-Modeline-Diagnostics
Lsp-Modeline-Workspace-Status Lsp-Ui-Doc Lsp-Ui Lsp-Ui-Sideline
Outline Prettify-Symbols Reftex Visual-Line Yas.  The major mode is LaTeX/P mode defined in latex.el:

Major mode in AUCTeX for editing LaTeX files.
See info under AUCTeX for full documentation.

Entering LaTeX mode calls the value of ‘text-mode-hook’,
then the value of ‘TeX-mode-hook’, and then the value
of ‘LaTeX-mode-hook’.
```

Comment: Above was for a tex file. Here is the same result for a lisp file ```Minor modes enabled in this buffer: Auto-Save Eldoc Font-Lock
Visual-Line Yas

The major mode is ELisp/d mode defined in elisp-mode.el:
```

Comment: Weird: I would restart Emacs and see if that clears it up. If not, I would turn off the cache with `(setq org-element-use-cache nil)` early in your init file and report it to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html).

Comment: Thank you. I already set org-element-use-cache to nil but this does not remove the warnings. I'll transmit this to this mailing list.

Comment: Ok, I finally just swept this issue under the rug with a ```(setq warning-suppress-types (append warning-suppress-types '((org-element-cache))))```. This works.